# i got hibernate SQL Syntax error using native query in Query Annotation (but this syntax is worked in console) * edited

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

first of all, i'm using (mysql 5.7, jdk1,8, spring boot)

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value= "set @COUNT = 0; \n"+
        "UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT\\:=@COUNT+1 WHERE f.id LIKE '%';", nativeQuery = true)
void update();
```

console message (hibernate error message) is

```
Hibernate: set @COUNT = 0; 
UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT:=@COUNT+1 WHERE f.id LIKE '%'; 
(error maessage)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT:=@COUNT+1 WHERE f.id LIKE '%'' at line 2
```

but this query is well worked in mysql console

```
set @COUNT = 0; UPDATE faq SET id = @COUNT:=@COUNT+1 WHERE f.id like '%';
```

plz help me... I've been searching and trying many solutions, but nothing worked

```
    ... UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT\\:=@COUNT+1 WHERE f.id LIKE '%';" ...)
    ... UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT|=@COUNT+1 WHERE f.id LIKE '%';" ...)
    ... UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT\\:=@COUNT+1 ;" ...)
    ... UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT\\:=(@COUNT+1) ;" ...)
    ... (UPDATE faq f SET f.id= @COUNT\\:=@COUNT+1 ;)" ...)
```

Comment: `@COUNT:=@COUNT+1 id` notice the ID!!! It should not be there

Comment: really sorry, there was a typo in the processing of posting questions!
I fixed it and the program still make an error ( ~ WHERE ~ -> id deleted),
Thanks for watching  my concern

Comment: You are trying to execute 2 queries at once. `set @COUNT = 0;` is the first. You can not do that. You can combine these queries by initializing the @count in your update query. But actually what you are doing is strange. You should not mess with the ID column in the first place.

Comment: how to combine those ?? i tried `update faq f set @COUNT\:=0, f.id = @COUNT\:=(@COUNT+1) ;` (this wasn't worked also in console ) actually i'm going to use id to index like '1. content, 2. content' ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute 2 queries at once. That does not work. You can combine these queries by initializing the @count in your update query like this:

```
UPDATE faq f 
JOIN (SELECT @count := 0) cnt
SET f.id = @COUNT := @COUNT + 1 
WHERE f.id LIKE '%'
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12e711/1)

Comment: finally, these codes are worked! appreciate for help and have a great week bro :)